# Solr autocomplete: Getting more information along with the suggestions

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I have found few ways to use autocomplete with solr: Faceting, TermComponent and Suggester

But in none of them I could find a functionality that includes say "id" and/or another field along with the autocomplete response.

Say I have the following data
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"test123"
}
{
 "id":2,
 "name":"test456"
}

Using above methods, if I ask for autocomplete for "test", I get results ["test123","test456"] but is there a way to get the id also along with the results?

Example: [{1,"test123"},{2,"test456"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you're trying to autocomplete, having a `StrField` or a `TextField` with the `KeywordTokenizer` (so you can lowercase, etc.) would allow you to perform a wild card prefix search (`field:foo*`). That way you can both autocomplete and get other fields from the documents returned (i.e. have `fl=name,id`).